# Submit button not working in Jquery Dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dialog

I use a dialog popup instead of a modal popup. The problem now is that the "submit" button does not work in the dialog popup, but it works in the modal popup. What do i have to do to make the submit button work in the dialog popup?

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div id="error"><span class="text-center"><p>Error</p></span></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input name="name" type="text" class="form-controls ease-out" id="name" placeholder="Name"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><input name="email" type="text" class="form-controls ease-out" id="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
        <div class="form-group"><textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-controls ease-out" required="" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="newsletter-btn ease-out" title="Send" name="submit" value="Send">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**DIALOG SCRIPT**

This is the script for opening the dialog

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var dlgtrigger = document.querySelector( '[data-dialog-contact]' ),
            contact = document.getElementById( dlgtrigger.getAttribute( 'data-dialog-contact' ) ),
            dlg = new DialogFx( contact );
            dlgtrigger.addEventListener( 'click', dlg.toggle.bind(dlg) );
                })();
</script>
```

**CONTACT SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value);
                }, "type the correct answer -_-");

            // validate contact form
            $(function() {
                $('#contact').validate({
                    rules: {
                        name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 2
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        message: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        answer: {
                            required: false,
                            answercheck: false
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        name: {
                            required: "Name required",
                            minlength: "At least 4 letters"
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: "Email required"
                        },
                        message: {
                            required: "Message required",
                            minlength: ""
                        },
                        answer: {
                            required: ""
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                            type:"POST",
                            data: $(form).serialize(),
                            url:"process.php",
                            success: function() {
                                $('#contact :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                $('#contact').fadeTo( "fast", 0.3, function() {
                                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                                });
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                $('#contact').fadeTo( "fast", 1, function() {
                                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Thank you, on before hand

Comment: Could you post the html for the `[data-dialog-contact]` element? also, is this `new DialogFx( contact )` one of your own constructors or part of a library you're using? If so, which one?

Comment: **html for the [data-dialog-contact] element:**

 `<a data-dialog-contact="contact" class="trigger btn btn_square"><svg><rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%"/></svg>Contact</a>`

**new DialogFx( contact )**: is not my own construction, i have taken it from [link](http://codepen.io/davidicus/pen/emgQKJ)